# In 4.7 CiviCase, why does reassigning a role not delete the old one?

Tags: civicase, issues

In 4.7, when managing a case, I try to reassign a role to another contact, but it adds a new one.

It should delete the old relationship. The button is an 'edit' pencil and the hover text says 'reassign'. There is a separate add role button.

The function that is invoked is relationship() in CRM/Contact/Page/AJAX.php but the "cid" value is not set (this should be the Contact Id of the current person holding that role). So the existing relationship is not deleted.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on the public demo at demo.civicrm.org? If so, you should file a bug report at issues.civicrm.org, and if possible, a suggested patch fix.

Answer (score 2):

This is a defect. See issue CRM-18698 for details.